# What is the css value #def?

Tags: css

I've seen this "#def" value popup on a couple things I've found. I tried 'googling' it and couldn't find anything. Anyone have some background? Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mbHB4/3/) showing the value being used.

```
body {
    background: #def;
}
```

Comment: It's just a color. Might be common. Might not.

Comment: A 3 digit color code, equivalent to #d0e0f0. It would be nearly white, with a touch of blue.

Comment: Make that #def == #ddeeff. Friday evening brain check.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`#def` is the hexadecimal value of the color `pale blue`

**EDIT:** As per Danko's comment below, `#def` is also the short version of `#ddeeff`

Comment: In addition is the short version of `#ddeeff`